# 'CTCTrainer' object has no attribute 'deepspeed' while training huggingsound speech recognition model training for my custom dataset

Tags: google-colaboratory, speech-recognition, training-data, huggingface, huggingface-trainer

I tried to train the "facebook/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-53" model in huggingface to my custom dataset.

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    learning_rate=3e-4,
    max_steps=10000,
    eval_steps=100,
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=8,
)
model_args = ModelArguments(
    activation_dropout=0.2,
    hidden_dropout=0.2,
)
```

```
output_dir = r'Output'
model.finetune(
    output_dir,
    train_data=train_data,
    token_set=token_set,
    training_args=training_args,
    model_args=model_args,
)
```

INFO:huggingsound.trainer:Building trainer...
INFO:huggingsound.trainer:Starting training...

╭─────────────────────────────── Traceback (most recent call last) ────────────────────────────────╮
│ in <cell line: 3>:3                                                                              │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/huggingsound/speech_recognition/model.py:361 in finetune │
│                                                                                                  │
│   358 │   │                                                                                      │
│   359 │   │   logger.info("Starting fine-tuning process...")                                     │
│   360 │   │                                                                                      │
│ ❱ 361 │   │   finetune_ctc(self.model_path, output_dir, processor, train_dataset, eval_dataset   │
│   362 │   │                                                                                      │
│   363 │   │   logger.info("Loading fine-tuned model...")                                         │
│   364                                                                                            │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/huggingsound/trainer.py:671 in finetune_ctc              │
│                                                                                                  │
│   668 │   if is_main_process(hftraining_args.local_rank):                                        │
│   669 │   │   processor.save_pretrained(hftraining_args.output_dir)                              │
│   670 │                                                                                          │
│ ❱ 671 │   train_result = trainer.train(resume_from_checkpoint=checkpoint)                        │
│   672 │   trainer.save_model()                                                                   │
│   673 │                                                                                          │
│   674 │   metrics = train_result.metrics                                                         │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1645 in train                    │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1642 │   │   inner_training_loop = find_executable_batch_size(                                 │
│   1643 │   │   │   self._inner_training_loop, self._train_batch_size, args.auto_find_batch_size  │
│   1644 │   │   )                                                                                 │
│ ❱ 1645 │   │   return inner_training_loop(                                                       │
│   1646 │   │   │   args=args,                                                                    │
│   1647 │   │   │   resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,                                │
│   1648 │   │   │   trial=trial,                                                                  │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1938 in _inner_training_loop     │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1935 │   │   │   │   │   self.control = self.callback_handler.on_step_begin(args, self.state,  │
│   1936 │   │   │   │                                                                             │
│   1937 │   │   │   │   with self.accelerator.accumulate(model):                                  │
│ ❱ 1938 │   │   │   │   │   tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)                      │
│   1939 │   │   │   │                                                                             │
│   1940 │   │   │   │   if (                                                                      │
│   1941 │   │   │   │   │   args.logging_nan_inf_filter                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/huggingsound/trainer.py:453 in training_step             │
│                                                                                                  │
│   450 │   │                                                                                      │
│   451 │   │   if (hasattr(self, 'use_amp') and self.use_amp) or (hasattr(self, 'use_cuda_amp')   │
│   452 │   │   │   self.scaler.scale(loss).backward()                                             │
│ ❱ 453 │   │   elif self.deepspeed:                                                               │
│   454 │   │   │   self.deepspeed.backward(loss)                                                  │
│   455 │   │   else:                                                                              │
│   456 │   │   │   loss.backward()                                                                │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
AttributeError: 'CTCTrainer' object has no attribute 'deepspeed'

How can I bypass this error and continue the training process?